# PHP contact form not working in FF but working in Edge IE chrome and safari

Tags: php, html, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

Dear folks the following code could be perfectly executed in IE (newest), Edge, Chrome and Safari but times out in FF, also it has issues with displaying the form in firefox.

In Firefox once i press submit, it starts running the sendform.php it executes correctly, **but it gets stuck once everything is filled out properly and it should send the form / email to me**.

the page is also in use. Tips and tricks for better / more secure code is appreciated.

The contact from code ( as in kontakt.php):

```
<?php
session_start();

$success='';
if($_SESSION['sent'] == '1')
{
    $success='<div class="container">
                <h3>Vielen Dank. Ihre Nachricht wurde übermittelt.</h3>
            </div>';

    $css='<style type="text/css">#phpcontactform{display:none;}</style>';

    unset($_SESSION['sent']);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <meta name="keywords" content="mieten,Bruchsal,Vermietung,Büro,Hallen,Standort,Industrie,Gewerbe,Gewerbepark,Produktion,Karlsruhe">
    <meta name="description" content="Vermietung von Büro, Hallen, Lager- und Produktionsflächen im Gewerbepark Bruchsal. Lageplan und Hallenplan.">
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">
    <meta name="page-topic" content="Kontaktformular">

    <title>GWB Kontakt</title>

    <link href="files/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="files/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <?=$css?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="files/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="files/myaffix.js"></script>

    <script> 

        $(document).ready(function () {

        //code for dynamic navbar banner
            myaffix();

            $(window).on("resize", function () {
                myaffix();   
            }); 

        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="logo">
        <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="images/banner.jpg" alt="Generic Banner">
    </div>

    <div id="placeme">
    </div>

    <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Gewerbepark Bruchsal</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="standort.html">Standort</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bilder.html">Bilder</a></li>
                        <li><a href="hallenplan.html">Hallenplan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ausstattung.html">Ausstattung</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <h1>Kontakt</h1>

        <hr>

        <p>ARES GmbH, Richard-Wagner-Straße 23, 50674 Köln
            <br>Telefon: 0221-2717290, Fax: 0221-2717291, Email: <a href="mailto:info@gewerbepark-bruchsal.de">info@gewerbepark-bruchsal.de</a>
        </p>

        <hr size="5px">

        <div class="container">

        <h2>Schreiben Sie uns direkt an</h2>

        <form id="phpcontactform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="files/sendform.php">

            <div class="form-group <?php if (isset($_SESSION['err']['name'])) {if ($_SESSION['err']['name'] == 'okay') {echo 'has-success has-feedback';} else {echo 'has-error has-feedback';}}  ?> ">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control <?php if (isset($_SESSION['err']['name'])) {if ($_SESSION['err']['name'] == 'okay') {echo 'alert alert-success';} else {echo 'alert alert-danger';}}  ?>" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ihr Name" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['post']['name']); ?>">
                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['err']['name'])) {if ($_SESSION['err']['name'] == 'okay') {echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>";} 
                    else {echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span><p class='text-danger'>{$_SESSION['err']['name']}</p>";} }?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group <?php if (isset($_SESSION['err']['email'])) {if ($_SESSION['err']['email'] == 'okay') {echo 'has-success has-feedback';} else {echo 'has-error has-feedback';}}  ?>">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control <?php if (isset($_SESSION['err']['email'])) {if ($_SESSION['err']['email'] == 'okay') {echo 'alert alert-success';} else {echo 'alert alert-danger';}}  ?>" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ihre Emailadresse" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['post']['email']); ?>">    
                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['err']['email'])) {if ($_SESSION['err']['email'] == 'okay') {echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>";} 
                    else {echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span><p class='text-danger'>{$_SESSION['err']['email']}</p>";} }?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="telefon">Telefon:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">          
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="telefon" id="telefon" placeholder="Ihre Telefonnummer - für schnellere Rücksprache" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['post']['telefon']); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group <?php if (isset($_SESSION['err']['message'])) {if ($_SESSION['err']['message'] == 'okay') {echo 'has-success has-feedback';} else {echo 'has-error has-feedback';}}  ?>">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="message">Nachricht:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control <?php if (isset($_SESSION['err']['message'])) {if ($_SESSION['err']['message'] == 'okay') {echo 'alert alert-success';} else {echo 'alert alert-danger';}}  ?>" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Ihr Anliegen" maxlength="1000"><?php echo ($_SESSION['post']['message']); ?></textarea>
                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['err']['message'])) {if ($_SESSION['err']['message'] == 'okay') {echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>";} 
                    else {echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span><p class='text-danger'>{$_SESSION['err']['message']}</p>";} }?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" name="senden" id="btn-senden" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Senden</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

        <?=$success?>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2015 ARES GmbH <a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The submit code ( as in sendform.php):

```
    <?php
//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
// date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
require "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

session_start();

foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
    $_POST[$k]=stripslashes($_POST[$k]);

    $_POST[$k]=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$k]));
}


// Fehlerkontrolle

// kreiere Fehlerarray

$err = array();


// Füge entsprechende Fehler hinzu
if(!checkLen('name'))
    $err['name']='Sie haben keinen Namen angegeben.';
else
    $err['name']='okay';

if(!checkLen('email'))
    $err['email']='Sie haben keine Email angegeben.';
elseif(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    $err['email']='Die Email scheint nicht gültig zu sein.';
else
    $err['email']='okay';

if(!checkLen('message'))
    $err['message']='Sie haben keine Nachricht hinterlassen.';
else
    $err['message']='okay';

// Speichere variablen in Seitenübergreifender Variable (SESSION)

$_SESSION['post']=$_POST;

$_SESSION['err']=$err;

//check if there are no errors

if(count(array_unique($err)) === 1)
{

    //create message body
    $msg=
    'Name:  '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
    Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
    IP: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'<br /><br />

    Message:<br /><br />

    '.nl2br($_POST['message']).'
    ';

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.XXXXX.XXX';
    // use
    // $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = "XXXX@XXXXX.XXX";

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = "XXXXXXXXX";

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress('XXXX@XXXX.XXX', 'Kontakt Formular');

    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = "Eine Anfrage von ".$_POST['name'].".";

    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    $mail->msgHTML($msg);


    //send the message
    $mail->send();

    //send silent notice that mail was sent
    $_SESSION['sent']= '1';



    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    unset($_SESSION['post']);
    unset($_SESSION['err']);

    exit;

}


// if there are errors by user filling the form
else
{

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    exit;

}


function checkLen($str,$len=2)
{
    return isset($_POST[$str]) && mb_strlen(strip_tags($_POST[$str]),"utf-8") > $len;
}

function checkEmail($str)
{
    return preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $str);
}

?>
```

I honestly do not know what causes, the issue, could be it is only my Firefox though i doubt it. Cheers and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does PHP get the request? Have you checked the webserver's and PHP's logfile(s)? Have you verified that Firefox sends the request? Have you verified that there is no error in the browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there are errors and Firefox is not sending a referrer so the redirect never gets sent.

Could you by any chance be sending any text that might accidentally become less than 3 characters when converted to UTF-8 or when otherwise processed?

Being able to see the contents of `$err` would help narrow that down or exclude that possibility.

Comment: as far as i could see no errors were send, using f12 watching the console.<br>how would i watch / check the webservers php logfiles? sorry but i'm a bit new to all this, the code/files are all under the folder /web/ <br> p.s: could someone with firefox check the page www.gewerbepark-bruchsal.de/kontakt.php maybe it is just my browser (which would be kinda okay) as then at least everyone else would get the correct page :|

Comment: Throw in a `var_dump($err)`. It will be ugly but you will be able to see what's in it.

Comment: where would i insert var_dump($err) in the main php or the processing php, and if its not redirecting where would i see it then? the output i mean? an example of how the changed file should look would be nice. :)

Comment: I would put it near `$_SESSION['err']=$err;` The output will probably show in the page (it will loook better in the page source) but the point is to diagnose this particular issue, so it's temporary.... when you identify and solve the problem you would take the var_dump out.